# chevy trail blazer 2005

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, trailblazer

I have just been putting water int he radiator (there is a leak) and ignoring the dex cool  - so you put water in the radiator in the front of the engine and then put coolant in the other one (back left) where is's labeled dex cool???

Comment: Make sure you use **distilled water**, and not tap water. Regardless of where you live, tap water contains very small quantities of chemicals and minerals. Though these help make tap water safe for human consumption, they are undesirable in engines. Distilled water on the other hand is 100% pure H2O. Most grocery stores sell it for very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Both the resevoir (Labeled Dex Cool) and the radiator are part of the cooling system.  By adding water to the radiator, you are diluting the 50/50 ratio of coolant and water.  Water has a higher freezing temperature, and lower boiling temperature than Dex Cool.  It would be wise to fix the leak, then bring the system back to a 50/50 coolant water mix to help protect the engine during extreme hot or cold ambient temperatures.